# Azure JavaScript Function Out to Service Bus Queue

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Service Bus Queue which is has duplicate detection set on.

A Function is triggered via CosmosDb in which it needs to then create a message in the Service Bus Queue; however, each attempt fails with a duplicate message error requiring MessageId.

Is there a Javascript SDK the function can access to create a new valid message payload?

If not, what is the message payload supposed to look like?

Comment: How do you put a message to the Service Bus Queue?
Through binding or an SDK?

Comment: I've tried with binding and messageId property seems to work with partitioning but not with duplicate detection. I've tried setting the value to something dynamic such as Date.now()

Comment: what is the exact error msg you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

When we activate duplication, the Windows Azure Service Bus will start to store a history of our messages. This period of time can be configured to range from only a few minutes to days. If a duplicate message is sent to the Service Bus, the service will automatically ignore the message.

In our case, in most scenarios duplicate detection is fine, but in some it was bad (especially with the 10 minute range). To get around this, we introduced a "breaker":
Put a value in your Service bus messageId property like below

```
msg.MessageId = messageId + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
```

If you just want to prevent "spamming" you might consider setting the duplicate detection window to the minimum (20 seconds). (Personally, I would love to see a threshold as low as 5 seconds).

The current ranges allowed are 20 seconds to 7 days.